# hyperref doesn't open URLs

Tags: hyperref, urls

when I use \url{www.apple.com} for instance, the url becomes clickable but if i click it i get a promt saying "Program can not be opened, -50"

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,.5}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, breaklinks=false, linkcolor=darkblue, menucolor=darkblue, pagecolor=darkblue, urlcolor=darkblue, frenchlinks=false, anchorcolor=darkblue, filecolor=darkblue, pdftitle={Praktikumsbericht}, pdfauthor={Henri Schmidt}, pdfpagemode=FullScreen, bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}


\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}

\url{www.apple.com}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem, so maybe it is because your system has not configured a valid application for http/https. However, a really correct URL always contains the link type and therefore would be `\url{https://www.apple.com}`. For short URLs without printed link type `https://`, `ftp://`, `mailto:` etc. use, e.g., `\href{https://www.apple.com}{www.apple.com}`.

Comment: You might want to specify which programme have been used as the PDF viewer as behaviour is programme dependent

Comment: BTW and off-topic: Using two encoding options for `inputenc` is seldom needed. If you want to switch from UTF8 to latin1 inside a document, you just need to start with UTF8. Also loading `url` (without option) before `hyperref` is seldom needed. Using package `parskip` with `scrartcl` is not recommended. You should use KOMA-Script option `parskip` instead. Options `11pt` and `a4paper` are defaults of `scrartcl` and therefore also not needed.

Comment: Welcome. // \usepackage{hyperref} instead of url may be an other good idea.

Comment: @MS-SPO the example loads hyperref, the problem is the missing protocol https://

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks: was hidden to me.